# Why does the free group of the singleton set contain all powers of the group element?

Tags: group-theory

I'm following Paolo Aluffi's Algebgra 0, and in II.5.5.1 it talks about free groups.

It comes to say that the free group of the singleton set $\{a\}$ is the set of all powers of $a$, identifying $a^0 = e$ where $e$ is the group identity.

I don't understand the intuition behind this definition. Why isn't the free group the group with 2 elements, $e$ and $a$, and such that $a*a=e$?

Note that I understand that free group is given by a universal property of commutativity of diagrams, but the intuition behind this seems to be that it captures $\{a\}$ in the most efficient way. So my question is simply why isn't the group with only two elements, if valid, considered a simpler encoding? Why are all the powers needed?

EDIT: Clarification

Comment: "Free" essentially means with as few assumptions as possible. If you have a group element $a$, then you automatically have all powers of $a$ in the group, because it's a group. But if you assume $a^2=e$ then, well, you're making an assumption. As for the universal property, if you have an arbitrary function $\{a\}\to G$ where $G$ is a group, you can't assume $a$ gets sent to an involution; it could be sent anywhere, even to an element of infinite order, so $a$ needs to have infinite order in $G$.

Comment: You have the wrong intuition. The definition of a free group requires that a free group with one generator have every cyclic group as a homomorphic image. Obviously, then, the free group must be infinite.

Comment: @runway44 I don't understand. If you have a group with only two elements $e$ and $a$, where $e$ is the group identity, and it is closed under the group operation, then it must be the case that $a * a = e$, does it not? Is anything else possible?

Comment: Every group containing $a$ contains $a^n$ for all $n\in \Bbb Z$. In some groups, we may have $a^2=1$ or $a^{17}=1$ (or even $a=1$) as additional facts. With the free group, we do not impose any of these restrictions. -- Wit your line of argument, wouldn't the group with *one* element $a$ be an even "simpler encoding"?

Comment: Are you familiar with group presentations?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen _"Every group containing $a$ contains $a^n$"_.

Yes, but since the set only contains one element, then everything that does not make $a^i = a$ for all $i$ falls outside the set.

_"wouldn't the group with one element  be an even "simpler encoding"_

It would. Aluffi suggests using that, but says "that is certainly a very special group-theoretic property''.

Comment: And I'll add something. By definition of free group, there must be a function $j$ that maps $A$ to $F(A)$. Now, if $F(A) = \{..., a^{-2}, a^{-1}, a^0=e, a, a^2, ...\}$, then $j$ is probably (?) identity, so all other elements in $F(A)$ would be superfluous when it comes to constructing the group homomorphism that would make any function from $A$ to another group decomposable in a function into the free group and a group homomorphism.

Comment: @IvanPerez You're not wrong about groups with two elements, but you're wrong to think groups with two elements are relevant. The set $\{a\}$ is only intended to be a subset of the free group it generates - indeed, a generating set - not intended to be the full set of nontrivial elements. If you assume the free group generated by $\{a\}$ has two elements, then you're making an assumption, which (as my previous comment mentions) is antithetical to what "freeness" is all about.

Comment: @PeterTaylor I don't know what you mean by "Group presentations", so I guess the answer is 'no'.

Comment: So how would you define, with your intuition, the free group on $2,3,\ldots$ elements?

Answer (score 3):

"Free" essentially means with as few assumptions as possible. So the the free group $F_S$ generated by a set $S$ must contain $S$ as a subset, and by group axioms must contain all "words" comprised of "letters" of $S$ as well as their inverses (which must exist). However, the whole **point** of "freeness" is to be as permissible as possible, or in other words as minimally restrictive as possible, or in other words as un-presumptuous as possible about its elements, which means we can't make any assumptions about group elements unless they follow logically from the group axioms. We cannot assume $a^2=e$.

(The point of "freeness" is not to be as "efficient" as possible, which I interpret you to mean as small as possible provided the set $S$ is a minimal generating set. In this case, the most "efficient," or I would simply say smallest, group containing $S$ as a minimal generating set would be the elementary abelian group $\mathbb{Z}_2^S$.)

Another way of thinking about the free group is that it is the *most universal* group containing $S$. That is, if there is any group $G$, and we have any function $f:S\to G$, then it extends uniquely to a group homomorphism $F_S\to G$. In the event $S=\{a\}$, we can't assume $a^2=e$ because then we couldn't be guaranteed the existence of a homomorphism $F_S\to \mathbb{Z}_3$ in which $a\mapsto 1$ (you can't have an element of order two map to an element of order three).

If $F_S$ is the free group on one element, then there must exist a one-to-one correspondence between functions $\{a\}\to G$ and group homomorphisms $F_S\to G$, and functions $\{a\}\to G$ are already in one-to-one correspondence with elements $G$. The range of the induced homomorphism $F_S\to G$ must contain an element of $G$ and hence the cyclic subgroup of $G$. By the first isomorphism theorem, the range is isomorphic to $F_S$ mod the kernel, so every cyclic group must be a quotient of $F_S$. We cannot assume $a$ has any finite order, because that would preclude us from extending a function $f:S\to G$ which maps $a$ to an element of order coprime to $n$ to a group homomorphism $F_S\to G$. Thus, $a$ has infinite order.

(This relates to what bof said in the comments.)

I also recommend looking into group presentations (as Peter Taylor mentions in the comments). In general, if $S$ is any set and $R$ is a set of "relations" then $\langle S\mid R\rangle$ is the "most universal" of "free-est" group generated by $S$ subject to the restraint that the elements of $S$ satisfy the relations specified by $R$. For example, we can get the cyclic group $\mathbb{Z}_n$ as $\langle a\mid a^n=e\rangle$ (often the "$=e$" part of the relations is suppressed). Or, we can get the dihedral group $D_n$ of rank $n$ (and order $2n$) as $\langle r,f\mid r^n,f^2,frf^{-1}=r^{-1}\rangle$ because for a minimal rotation $r$ and flip $f$ within this group, all of the relations between $r$ and $f$ can be deduced from three: that applying $r$ $n$-times returns to normal, that $f$ is a flip (i.e. involution), and conjugating a rotation by a reflection yields its inverse (which is true of every rotation and reflection in the plane).

Note that if $R$ has "more" relations than $R'$, then $\langle S,R\rangle$ will be a quotient of $\langle S,R'\rangle$, as making more assumptions about the group elements is more restrictive and yields a smaller group. If $R$ is the "empty set" of relations, so no assumptions are made at all about how the elements of the generating set $S$ interact, then we get the free group $F_S=\langle S\mid \varnothing\rangle$. This suggests $F_S$ is "as big" as possible containing $S$ (as a minimal generating set, anyway), which is in some sense the *opposite* as being the "most efficient" containing $S$.

Another illustration of this "free" idea is *free products* $G\ast H$, in which we want the "freest" group containing $G$ and $H$ as subgroups. It must contain all the elements of $G$ and $H$, and must contain all "words" of $G\sqcup H$, but we cannot assume anything that allows us to simplify these words except the operations already given in $G$ and $H$. In terms of presentations then it becomes intuitive that $\langle S_1,R_1\rangle \ast \langle S_2,R_2\rangle \cong \langle S_1\sqcup S_2,R_1\sqcup R_2\rangle$ for example.

Comment: Thanks. I don't really follow your logic in _"So the the free group  generated by a set  *must* contain  as a subset, and by group axioms must contain all "words" comprised of "letters" of  as well as their inverses (which must exist)."_

Why would F(S) have to contain S at all?

Why would all words of elements of S have to be distinct? What's the point of having more elements than S at all?

Comment: @IvanPerez That's not logic, that's definitional. We're using $S$ to generate a group, so of course the elements of the group we generate can be expressed in terms of $S$. The words need to be distinct in order be as "least presumptuous" (i.e. free) as possible. We're having more elements than $S$ because, again, we're *generating* a group that is to be universal. Not every function $f:S\to G$ (where $G$ is a group and $S$ a set) can be a group homomorphism for any operation on $S$ at all, but it can be if you extend $S$ to existing inside a larger structure.

Comment: If you want a function $f:S\to G$ to extend to a homomorphism $F_S\to G$ at all, its range contains $f(S)$, so must contain all elements of the form, $f(s_1)^{e_1}\cdots f(s_k)^{e_k}$ in $G$, which are mapped to from elements $s_1^{e_1}\cdots s_k^{e_k}$ in $F_S$, and the second you assume any two distinct words equal each other you're automatically preventing yourself from extending a function where the words get mapped to different elements of $G$ (which is always possible). So no two distinct words can equal each other in $F_S$.